# Сито, задача, только через иф - елсе

Tags: c++, if

> Железные шары 4 размеров сортируются за диаметром с помощью трех сит, которые расставлены друг над другом. Каждое сито имеет диаметры только одного размера, которые отвечает одному из трех диаметров шаров, исключая шар наибольшего размера. За известными диаметрами сит расставить их в порядке, который бы обеспечил сортировку шаров.

Я сделал сортировку сита, как мне прогнать через них шары и правильно вывести, помогите.

Примерная блок схема снизу.

[image: Примерная блок схема]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;



int main(){

int a,b,c,p;
cin>>a>>b>>c;
int x1,x2,x3,x4;
cin>>x1>>x2>>x3>>x4;

    if(a<b){
        p=a;
        a=b;
        b=p;
    }if(b<c){
        p=b;
        b=c;
        c=p;
    }if(a<b) {
        p=a;
        a=b;
        b=p;

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас у Вас a - наибольшие дырки, b - поменьше, а c - самые маленькие. Вот и проверяйте x в этом порядке:

```
if (x >= a) 
    не лезет никуда 
else if (x >= b) 
   между a и b
else if (x >= c) 
   между b и c
else
  всех проскочил
```